# Is there sphinx like support for godoc to directly reference code docs from user docs?

Tags: go, documentation

Coming from python/sphinx I'm use to having a "docs" folder (in sphinx it would be written in rst format) with usage/tuts/reference/etc info and in those docs I can directly reference my code docs. The docs folder of rst files is rendered to html on build.

So in my "how-to" user doc I can point directly to a docstring for a function and that code doc snippet will render in my how-to doc.

Also, I like all the added Rst features and plugins for other languages and stuff.

Is there something in the godoc ecosystem that does this? Can I use sphinx with godoc? Doesn't seem to have official support and all I found was this valiant yet dead effort: https://github.com/chrisdoherty4/sphinxcontrib-golangdomain. Also, it appears godoc is super limited with what outputs it supports so I can't render to an intermediary format and pull that into sphinx easily.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any tool that allows integrating godoc into sphinx, however you could do the following (since your goal is HTML rendering):

- generate your "how-to" as you are used to
- link to the godoc-generated reference documentation (example: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/fluhus/godoc-tricks#NewExamples)

If you want to self-host the generated godoc, you can have a look at:

- https://code.rocket9labs.com/tslocum/godoc-static
- https://code.pfad.fr/vanitydoc/ (disclaimer: I made this one - feel free to reach out if you want to work on a .rst export :)